# My change to the default font size reverts at startup

Tags: fonts

When I start Emacs with `emacs -Q --eval '(set-face-attribute (quote default) nil :height 180)`, the font changes for a split-second, but then returns to its default. Same thing if I put the code in my init file.

If I deliberately cause an error with `emacs -Q --eval '(progn (set-face-attribute (quote default) nil :height 180) (bing))`, the change sticks. But this doesn't work if I put the code in my init file—I guess that whatever mechanism Emacs uses to recover from init-file errors doesn't prevent the font-size-revert code from running.

**How do I get Emacs to accept my default font size?**

I'm running Emacs 25.1.2 (from [kelleyk's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs)) on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Is there a font that you can use in your `default-frame-alist` or `initial-frame-alist` that will serve to set the default to your liking such that you can forego using `set-face-attribute`?  For example, on OSX --with-x  my applicable frame parameter is `(font . "-Adobe-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-m-110-iso10646-1")`.

Comment: @lawlist I want to be able to set the default size conditionally (specifically, one size for when I'm using an external monitor and another for when I'm using my laptop's screen). I was able to do this by manually setting face attributes in Emacs 24. Will I still be able to do this with `default-frame-alist` or `initial-frame-alist`?

Comment: What you are experiencing is likely a bug worthy of a bug report to the Emacs team.  My idea is meant to be a potential workaround until your bug gets fixed.  When I make frames during my Emacs session after startup, I rely upon the `default-frame-alist` and I also pass along additional frame parameters programmatically based on a situation -- e.g., `(make-frame (list '(name . "ZTREE")))`  You can have a function that determines your situation and passes the appropriate parameter based thereon.  See also `modify-frame-parameters` and `set-frame-parameter`.

Comment: This works fine for me on Emacs 25.1.50.3. Maybe one of the patches applied by kelleyk has interacted with something?

Comment: @lawlist I don't think this is a reportable bug unless it can be reproduced on an official Emacs build. Not sure what exactly is in the linked PPA

Comment: To answer your question to @lawlist: Yes, you can set `default-frame-alist` with conditionally determined values computed at startup time. (Likewise, `initial-frame-alist`, but I doubt that you need to fiddle with that.)

Comment: @Tyler - I'm seeing this in the stock emacs supplied with Ubuntu 17.10.  When I set the default face using customize-face, it works until I restart.  Then, when I restart, it initially starts with the font I set up, but after about 1/4 of a second the font switches to the system default (DejaVu Mono 11.3pt).  Going back in the customize faces menu, the settings there have been changed to that.  I think it's something that ubuntu's startup scripts do.

Comment: ... which it turns out is because it's pulling information out of gnome config and changing the font there.  See: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32664/19074

Comment: Possible duplicate of [something changes the default face in my .emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32641/something-changes-the-default-face-in-my-emacs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add your own command-line switch, and deal with it in your init file, like this:

```el
(setq big-font-p (member "--big-font" command-line-args))
(setq command-line-args (delete "--big-font" command-line-args))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             (if big-font-p
                 '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-18") ;; Big font
               '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-12"))) ;; Default font
```

In this case, if the option `--big-font` is not specified on the command-line, then your default font will be used.

Comment: Setting `default-frame-alist`, as originally suggested by lawlist, seems to work fine. Thanks, everyone.