# something changes the default face in my .emacs

Tags: faces, gui

Debian Sid, emacs25, cinnamon 3.2.7

In my `~/.emacs` I have

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil [...] :foundry "microsoft" :family "Consolas")))))
```

When I login in X using, e.g. `xfce` and start `emacs` I have that the default face uses `Consolas` as I want, when I login using `cinnamon` and start `emacs` I have that the default face uses `LucidaTypewriter` (that is a bitmapped font)!

In the second case `M-x customize-face RET default RET` shows me a customization buffer where the font family is `LucidaTypewriter`, while in my
`~/.emacs` I still have a reference to `Consolas`.

«edit1»
I forgot to mention: if I evaluate the `custom-set-faces` form, as it is stored
 inside my `.emacs`, during a Cinnamon session the default face is reversed from `LucidaTypewriter` to `Consolas` as expected.

I have no problems on the Emacs side (at least I hope so...), I just want to understand what is happening and, possibly, avoid the small inconvenience of resetting the face to my liking.
«/edit1»

«edit2» 
I'm going to address some questions raised in a comment (thank you @jimmij).

1. Usually I start Emacs from the panel, the command that is used is always (i.e., in Cinnamon and in XFCE)

   ```
   /usr/bin/emacsclient -c -a ""
   ```

   but if in a Cinnamon session I start Emacs from the command line I have exactly the same behaviour ("wrong" font).
2. The `~/.emacs` file is correctly evaluated (I see all my customizations) and no error is reported.
3. The `*Messages*` buffer

   ```
   Loading 00debian-vars...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50asymptote.el (source)...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
   Loading debian-ispell...
   Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
   Loading debian-ispell...done
   Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el (source)...
   Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/slime-autoloads.el (source)...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el (source)...done
   Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50texlive-lang-english.el (source)...done
   For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
   Mark set
   ```
4. Re X resources database

   ```
   $ xrdb -q | grep -i emacs | grep -vi xemacs
   $
   ```

   I have no resources concerning Emacs, irrespective of who set them.

«/edit2»

Who's playing behind my back? and how could I  preempt their move?

---

ps the `[...]` ellipsis in the code snippet just stays for a long sequence of default values.

---

---------------------------- ***UPDATE*** -----------------------------
ps (writing 24h later) installing the `emacs25-lucid` package "*solved*" my problem, in the sense that now a freshly started Emacs uses Consolas — however, this at least leaves open my question "Who's playing behind my back?" with respect to the most common choice of installing the GTK gui version of Emacs.

Comment: What happens when you directly set *consolas* in the cinamon session? (place cursor at the last parenthesis and run C-x C-e).

Comment: @jimmij  _"What happens when you directly set consolas in the cinnamon session?"_  The default face uses again Consolas (I've edited my Q).

Comment: And how do you start emacs, from terminal or graphical interface? If the later then check what command hide underneath. It looks as if .emacs file was not evaluated , perhaps it was invoked with `-q` option? Other things to check are a *Messages* buffer (pehaps there are some errors) and .Xresources/.Xdefaults files (although I believe settings from .emacs should override them).

Comment: @jimmij Thank you for the good questions, Being unable to reply in the format of a comment I have edited my question.

Comment: Does `(define-key special-event-map [config-changed-event] 'ignore)` help? (refer https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25228#152)

Comment: @npostavs I've reinstalled `emacs25`, I've modified my `.emacs` according to your suggestion and voilà, when,I start Emacs in a Cinnamon session, NO LUCIDA TYPEWRITER! Thank you very much! — If you care you could write your comment as an answer.  I've not read your link for now, does it explain what is changing the face?

Comment: For the records: I faced the same problem and it was in Xfce (Linux Mint 19).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Who's playing behind my back?" with respect to the most common choice of installing the GTK gui version of Emacs.

The GTK build of Emacs supports [GConf](https://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) settings, which is what is causing the font change "behind your back".  To disable GConf settings add this to your .emacs:

```
(define-key special-event-map [config-changed-event] 'ignore)
```

Prior to Emacs 25.1 the font setting via GConf was broken somehow, which prevented this issue from showing before then.  See also [Bug#25228](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25228).

Comment: `gconftool-2 --dump / | grep -i lucida` and variations of that command produce an empty string...  I piped the output to `less` and looked at all the instances of `font` — the only references are to `Sans 10` and `Monospace 10` but `fc-match` thinks that `Sans` is `Vera.ttf` and `Monospace` is `VeraMono.ttf` so I'd give an arm (figuratively) to know where that `LucidaTypewriter` came from or, more to the point, I will accept the answer... OTOH ignoring the `config-changed-event` did the trick of preventing `GConf` from doing its evil, so thank you very much, ciao

Comment: @gboffi you can try debugging the `dynamic-setting-handle-config-changed-event` function to see why it happens, it looks like it might be using `(font-get-system-font)` instead of any explicit font setting to decide the new font.

Comment: In the scratch buffer, `(font-get-system-font)` evaluates to `"Monospace 11"`  — that's interesting because, according to `gconftool-2`, the system monospaced font is `"Monospace 10"` but this could be related, as in the bug report  you've mentioned, to slightly different ideas of the screen resolution.  Re debugging, from the same bug report it looks not something at the elisp level but requiring a binary with debugging symbols and a bit of practice with `gdb` so I give up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was driving me crazy: I could see my theme face appear in a glimpse and disappear a fraction of second later... From the bug report you cite, comment 20: "Such configuration settings should never override anything specified by the user in her .emacs." This was more than 2 years ago... :-(